# jQuery addClass on scroll 'at' a div

Tags: jquery

I have had a good look around and I am having a real hard time here with some jQuery, I can only find solutions to add a class to a div when scrolling but only by a certain numeric pixel number.

Here is a jsfiddle of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/sqz75b9g/

Also copied in the jquery. Now this works great under the purpose that the user has scrolled 500 pixels down. But I would like the addClass to happen **when the user reaches the .content div**, **not just a pixel height**.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
    $(function() {
    var header = $('header');
    var menu = $('#menu');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 500) {
            header.addClass('dark');
            menu.addClass('dark');
        } else {
            header.removeClass('dark');
            menu.removeClass('dark');
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
var hieghtThreshold = $(".content").offset().top;
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sqz75b9g/6/

```
$(function() {
var header = $('header');
var menu = $('#menu');
var hieghtThreshold = $(".content").offset().top;
var hieghtThreshold_end  = $(".content").offset().top +$(".content").height() ;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= hieghtThreshold && scroll <=  hieghtThreshold_end ) {
        header.addClass('dark');
        menu.addClass('dark');
    } else {
        header.removeClass('dark');
        menu.removeClass('dark');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: This works great thank you, i'm assuming my 'else' code is wrong, how would it then work for it to removeClass after its passed the .content

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use `.offset().top`:

```js
$(function() {
  var header = $('header');
  var menu = $('#menu');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= $('.content').offset().top) { // check the offset top
      header.addClass('dark');
      menu.addClass('dark');
    } else if(scroll >= $('.content').offset().top+$('.content').height()){ // check the scrollHeight
      header.removeClass('dark');
      menu.removeClass('dark');
    }
  });
});
```

---

`if (scroll >= $('.content').offset().top) {` checks the specific element is in the view.

`} else if(scroll >= $('.content').offset().top+$('.content').height()){` This will check if element is passed from the view.

Comment: This works great! Can't believe how simply that worked, one last thing which I guess in my code is wrong, is the else { once it is beyond .content, it doesnt removeClass.

Comment: thanks for your answer. complete it so i can give u +1

Comment: @HeyImArt for  this i guess you need to check for `offset().top + height`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offset() method to know where is your element:

```
var header = $('header');
var menu = $('#menu');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $('.element').offset().top; // look at this

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        header.addClass('dark');
        menu.addClass('dark');
    } else {
        header.removeClass('dark');
        menu.removeClass('dark');
    }
});
```